# How to change environments with google optimize

Tags: google-optimize

Anyone know how to switch environments in Google Optimize.
currently google optimize is set to a production environment mySite.com. 
Do I need to create a new account for my dev environment by editing container information, or can I just edit the property name under Google Analytics to match my Dev Analytics ?

Container setup >

**Container information**

```
mySite.com
XXX-xxxxxxx
```

**Google Analytics**

Property

```
myWebsite
XX-xxxxxxxxx-xx
```

**Views**

Master View

Comment: Could you able to fix the problem. If so could you please share the solution